# Central Limit Theorem for difference of sums of indicator random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

Consider two sums of independent random variables,
$S_1 = \sum_{i=1}^N X_i$ and
$S_2 = \sum_{i=1}^N Y_i$.
Both $X_i$ and $Y_i$ take only values $0$ or $1$ for all $i$ and they are not equally distributed.
What is the shortest and most elegant way to prove that there exists $K>0$ such that for all $N$ the following holds?
$$P( S_2 - S_1 \geq E[S_2] - E[S_1]) \geq K $$

Can one apply the Central Limit Theorem in this case?

Answer (score 2):

If $(X_i)$ is i.i.d., $(Y_i)$ is i.i.d. and $(X_i)$ and $(Y_i)$ are independent, this follows from the central limit theorem applied to the i.i.d. sequence $(Z_i)$ defined by 
$$
Z_i=X_i-Y_i-E(X_1)+E(Y_1).
$$
To wit, considering the events
$$
A_N=[S_2-S_1\geqslant E(S_2)-E(S_1)],
$$
one gets
$$
A_N=[U_N\geqslant0]=\left[\frac{U_N}{\sqrt{N}}\geqslant0\right],\qquad U_N=Z_1+\cdots+Z_N.$$ 
Introducing some standard normal random variable $U$, the central limit theorem shows that, when $N\to\infty$,
$$
P(A_N)\to P(U\geqslant0)=\tfrac12,
$$
hence $P(A_N\geqslant0)\geqslant\frac13$ for every $N$ large enough, say $N\geqslant N_0$. On the other hand, $P(A_N)\gt0$ for every $N\leqslant N_0$ hence
$$
\inf\limits_{N\geqslant1}P(A_N)\gt0.
$$

Comment: Is the Lyapunov condition that allows to use the CLT always satisfied?

Comment: I didn't say that the random variables are identically distributed!

Comment: Which is the reason why this answer starts with its initial sentence. You did not specify either whether the Xs were independent of the Ys. Are they? All these should be mentioned *explicitely*  in the question.